# Regex split string by new line and also include empty lines new lines

Tags: regex, lua

```
my_line = [[this
is
a

test]]

split_file = string.match(my_line, "[^\r\n]+|^[ \t\n]*$")
print(#split_file)
```

the above code doesn't work and I don't know why

```
string.match(my_line, "[^\r\n]+")
```

This works, but it only matches the words, so my array would look like this `["this", "is", "a", "test"]`

While I want the array to be

```
["this", "is", "a", "\n", "test"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which language are you using, so in JavaScript using global (g) and multi-line (m) flags -

```js
st = `this
is
a

test`;
console.log(JSON.stringify(st.match(/[^\r\n]+|^[ \t\n]*/gm))); // ["this","is","a","\n","test"]
```

Comment: Ah.. I'm using lua, and I just looked it up and lua doesn't support the | operator.. ashame.

Comment: You can always use a map (or loop) like `console.log(JSON.stringify(st.split('\n').map(x=> {if (x.trim()=='') {return '\n';} else {return x;}}))); // ["this","is","a","\n","test"]` in JavaScript.
Basically split the text with newlines, and then loop over to compare each value (trimmed) with empty string and replace it with newline

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone I'm afraid Lua doesn't have a `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

use `string.match(my_line, "[^\r\n]*")`

the "+" means one or more

the "*" means 0 or more

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem which unfortunately is somewhat awkward to solve in Lua.

#### Reading files / stdin line by line

If you're lucky, your string comes from a file / stdin. Then you can use [`io.lines`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.lines):

```lua
local lines = {}
for line in io.lines() do
    table.insert(lines, line)
end
```

replace `io.lines()` with `io.lines(filename)` to read from a file rather than stdin; `file:lines()` also works. The file handle will be closed automatically when the loop finishes; if you use `break`, you may have to close the file handle manually in older Lua versions (otherwise it will be hanging around until the next garbage collection cycle).

#### Splitting strings by linebreaks

First, what's a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)? Usually it's `\n` (LF, Unix) or `\r\n` (CRLF, Windows); "classic Mac OS" apparently used just `\r`. Let's consider just LF and CRLF.

The last line will also often not have a trailing linebreak, and you need to be able to deal with that too (edge case: does the empty string have no lines, or does it have one empty line?).

##### `[^\r\n]*`

A pattern like `[^\r\n]*` *can't work* when passed to `gmatch`, since it will treat `\r\n` (CRLF) as two empty lines, when it's really just one empty line.

Furthermore, this doesn't work on LuaJIT: Try

```lua
for m in ("a\nb\nc"):gmatch"[^\n]*" do print(m) end
```

This will match empty lines which aren't there. It's not even clear whether LuaJIT is "non-spec-compliant" here - since `*` matches "zero or more" greedily, adding arbitrary matches of length zero seems permissible, so long as you don't "shorten" a match, which LuaJIT doesn't do.

##### Output format

> While I want the array to be `["this", "is", "a", "\n", "test"]`

This is an odd format. Why include the newline in one string, but not the others? `["this", "is", "a", "", "test"]` is more reasonable, so that's what I will be implementing; it's easy to turn one into the other, though.

##### Implementation

The first thing you could do is to normalize line feeds, leaving you with just LFs to deal with; a simple `str = str:gsub("\r\n", "\n")` will replace all CRLFs with LFs.

After you have done that, add a trailing linefeed, if it doesn't exist already: `if str:sub(-1) ~= "\n" then str = str .. "\n" end`.

Then you can simply loop over the lines using `str:gmatch("(.-)\n")` (match as few characters as possible until a linefeed).

Putting it together:

```lua
local function splitlines(str)
    local lines = {}
    if str == "" then return lines end -- special case: empty string - no lines
    str = str:gsub("\r\n", "\n") -- normalize linefeeds
    if str:sub(-1) ~= "\n" then str = str .. "\n" end -- add trailing linefeed
    for line in str:gmatch("(.-)\n") do -- match lines
        table.insert(lines, line)
    end
    return lines
end
local my_str = [[this
is
a

test]]
for i, line in ipairs(splitlines(my_str)) do
    print(i, line)
end
```

Output is as expected:

```
1   this
2   is
3   a
4   
5   test
```

##### "Manual" implementation

Alternatively, we can go "full manual mode" and use `string.find` (or even manual `sub`/`byte` operations) to find linebreaks. Here's such an implementation (iterator) I wrote a while ago; it also deals with CR linefeeds properly (in hindsight, that was probably unnecessary):

```lua
-- Lines are possibly empty substrings separated by CR, LF or CRLF
-- A trailing linefeed is ignored
local function lines(str)
    local line_start = 1
    -- Line iterator
    return function()
        if line_start > #str then
            return
        end
        local linefeed_start, _, linefeed = str:find("([\r\n][\r\n]?)", line_start)
        local line
        if linefeed_start then
            line = str:sub(line_start, linefeed_start - 1)
            line_start = linefeed_start + (linefeed == "\r\n" and 2 or 1)
        else
            line = str:sub(line_start)
            line_start = #str + 1
        end
        return line
    end
end
```

Usage:

```lua
for line in lines(my_str) do
    print(line)
end
```

Again the output is as expected:

```lua
this
is
a

test
```

Comparing readability, finding nuances where the semantics differ and benchmarking are left as exercises to the reader :)